# EF comparing strings of dates in format "YYYYMMDD" in a linq query?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq

In my table there is a varchar field which contains dates in format YYYYMMDD (that's how SAP stores dates). Anyway to run a query against this field similar to:

```
from c in db.Set<MyTable>()
   where c.Date >= "20120921" && c.Date <= "20121021"
   select c
```

I tried to do a String.Compare, but EF can't translate that to SQL.

```
where String.Compare(c.Date, "20120921") >= 0
```

I also tried to convert both strings to int and do the comparison, and again EF doesn't support that.

Comment: What's wrong with the "similar to" query at the top?

Comment: why can't u parse dates with format and then use in query?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson First one won't compile, cannot apply operator to strings

Comment: @Roar That would be really slow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [`SqlFunctions.DateDiff`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466158.aspx) method overload that takes three `string`s, like this:

```
var res = from c in db.Set<MyTable>()
   where SqlFunctions.DateDiff("dd", c.Date, "20120921") >= 0
      && SqlFunctions.DateDiff("dd", c.Date, "20121021") < 0
   select c
```

Comment: Yes it worked thanks, I had to replace "ms" with "dd"

Comment: @aryaxt Perfect, thanks for letting me know that you changed `ms` for `dd` - I edited the answer, in case someone else needs to do something of this nature. I also edited the title to mention SAP strings to make your question easier to find.

Comment: FYI: This makes the query extremely slow

Comment: @aryaxt That's strange. Do you have an index on the column that corresponds to `c.Date`?